# Is it possible to have multiple triggers with the same trigger event and action time (before/after)

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I know it is possible to have multiple triggers, but is it possible to have multiple triggers with the same trigger event and action time (before/after).

This is referring to MySQL version 6 and later.

Comment: There isn't a MySQL version 6 it goes from 5.7 to 8?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the order of execution is not guaranteed, so don't make them rely on each other or require occurring in a particular sequence. If you require sequenced actions, use a single trigger for those actions

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to have multiple triggers for same type (delete, insert..) and time points (before, after ..).

For such situations, you would rather write what you want to execute in a set of procedures with relevant parameters and then call them from the trigger passing right values and in the order that you wish.